# Policy routing: "from" in routes

Tags: networking

I'm trying to understand what is the use of employing the "from" keyword in routes, as opposed to rules.

I have two routes:
default from 2001:470:aaaa::/48 dev ipv6-tunnel metric 100 pref medium
default via 2001:bbb:ccc::1 dev eth0 metric 1024 pref medium

These rules were created with:
/sbin/ip -6 route add default from 2001:470:aaaa::/48 dev ipv6-tunnel
/sbin/ip -6 route add default via 2001:bbb:ccc::1 dev eth0

And a packet that gets sent from the 2001:470:aaaa::/48 prefix ends up using the second default rule, as opposed to the first one, which is supposed to be more specific (in the sense that it specifies a "from" prefix).

any clues?

thank you!

mario